# Wordpress Plugin Development - Add image selection

Tags: php, wordpress

I am struggling to find out how to add an image to a plugin i am building.need to be able to bring up the dialog for upload/select from gallery images from within my plugin.

Any ideas??

Comment: -1: Where is your research?

Comment: this might work for you http://wordpress.org/plugins/frontend-uploader/

Answer (score 1):

i found a solution, its here if any one else is interested.

http://www.webmaster-source.com/2010/01/08/using-the-wordpress-uploader-in-your-plugin-or-theme/

thanks for the comments though guys